# request.subdomain is not being set in Rails 3 during conditional routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I'm trying to setup Subdomains in Rails 3 per [Ryan Bates screencast on subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3). However it's not working for me. I have the following setup:

```
# routes.rb
constraints(Subdomain) do
  get 'devices' => 'devices#all'
end

# lib/subdomain.rb
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    # binding.pry
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain == "admin"
  end
end
```

Loading the url `admin.localhost:3000/devices` should route me to `devices#all`, however I get a routing error `Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/devices"` Clearly my routing isn't working.

I setup a `pry` debug session where the comment is above, and it gets hit, so my constraint is working, but I get the following output:

```
[1] pry(Subdomain)> request.subdomain
=> ""
[2] pry(Subdomain)> request.subdomains
=> []
[3] pry(Subdomain)> request.host
=> "admin.localhost"
```

So rails isn't picking up the admin portion of the url and placing it into the subdomain variable. While I could easily just use the host value to filter to the admin routes, I'd like to keep things clean and correct.

How come rails isn't setting the subdomain value?

---

**Edit**

Both [jdoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056789/33226) and [coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056793/33226) are correct with their answers. What was throwing me off was that I was also using `pow` and `xip.io` to access the site and getting the same error. Which was odd because `http://admin.app_name.192.168.1.68.xip.io/devices` has a tld > 1. What was happening was that the subdomain for `xip` was `admin.app_name.192.168.1.68`, which also fails given the matches logic and doesn't route.

Comment: > How come rails isn't setting the subdomain value?

I think it's still Rack at that point.

Comment: @OscarDelBen it's not. It's ActionDispatch `request.inspect # => <ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000102b8dc08`

Comment: +1 for additional clarification on Pow & Xip.io. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Because there isn't a subdomain as far as Rails considers it.**

Rails expects you to provide a [Top-Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (TLD) length for TLDs with more than 1 dot. For example, if you had `bbc.co.uk` it would pickup "bbc" as the subdomain unless you specified the TLD length is 2, in which case the subdomain would be blank:

```
request.subdomain(2) #=> ""
```

This is also why you're seeing `subdomains` return an empty array: the last two segments are being discarded automatically. You could specify `0` as the TLD length to get back "admin", but that code will break in production with a real domain name, so I don't recommend it.

I recommend using a domain like admin.yourapp.dev that is routed back to your computer via localhost to make your app properly detect a subdomain. Just edit /etc/hosts to do it simply.

If you're curious, [here is the Rails source for the `subdomain` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5f67cfeda116f2b932ef72781420aa37e62437ca/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L169).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked yours correct since I should have looked at the source for subdomain method before posting on SO. :X

Answer (score 7):

Try using special address: http://admin.lvh.me:3000/devices

Or set:

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0
```

in your development.rb and restart your app.

Comment: Thanks @jdoe for the answer. Hitting admin.lvh.me helped to clear things up greatly.

Comment: setting action_dispatch_tld is a nice software only solution. seems to work for my needs